# Android ICS Camera behaviour

Tags: android, camera, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In case of ICS if we keep swiping while boot animation is happening do we expect the camera to turn on during or after boot to home screen happens ?

Answer (score 0):

The camera should turn on only after the home screen appears.